# Which winter road cycling shoes are rated for sub-15° F weather?

Tags: winter, shoes

Most of the road shoes I've found only seem to be rated to around 25° or so. Living in New England I'd like something colder. Does anyone know of road shoes rated for colder temps?

(They'll be used for commuting and weekend road rides)

Update: I have new Neoprene booties (Pearl Izumi Elite Barrier Shoe Cover) but find that they're only comfortable down to about 25°F or so.

Comment: How many socks are you wearing? Generally road shoes tend to want the opposite of what you want (to stay ventilated), so you may want to look at MTB shoes if you're using cleats.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Batman and DRH. In the coldest conditions I'll wear a couple of pairs of socks (Assos do some midwinter socks which are very good but quite expensive) plus some booties. But I wear the same shoes all year round.

Comment: To add, I generally don't use my cycling shoes in the winter (too much wind, too low temps in the midwest). Depending on where you are in NE, [icebike](http://icebike.org/Clothing/footwear.htm) may be useful.

Comment: What does it mean "cycling shoes"? Are you riding clipless or flat?

Comment: I don't recommend multiple socks for most people.  If you have tight fitting shoes, it will most certainly make the problem worse.

Comment: @jimirings Not sure why you put this question on hold - the problem I'm trying to solve seems pretty clear. As far as being objective, the vast majority of questions are subjective, such as your, "Is it safe to use a spacer that reaches above the steerer tube?"

Comment: I put it on hold because it's a product recommendation question, which the [community has decided is off topic](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/828/adding-shopping-recommendations-to-the-vote-to-close-page). And yes, the problem that you're trying to solve is clear: What shoes should I buy? The problem with this question is not that it's subjective. The problem is that it tends to garner answers where each answer is equally valid. Basically, it's a subset of the "[too broad](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)" closure reason.

Comment: Incidentally, you can flag it for reopening and the other mods will look at it and weigh in on it.

Answer (score 5):

The vast majority of cycling shoes (road and mountain) are well ventilated and not suitable for cold weather riding.  Lake makes an excellent winter boot (I have several pairs).  45NRTH makes the Wolvhammer, which I haven't tried, but have heard good things about.  There isn't a market for cold weather "road" shoes since generally road bikes become unsafe/unuseable after there is ice/snow on the road.

As far as getting the most out of the footwear you are using, I recommend NOT putting thick socks in your summer shoes.  Most people's summer riding shoes are close fitting, and adding extra thicker socks make keeping your feet warm harder since it compresses your blood vessels and restricts circulation.  If you can't stay warm with normal socks and booties / chem packs, you may need to look at purchasing a set of winter shoes with extra room for thicker socks.  My summer shoes are all 44s.  For winter, my shoes/boots are all 46s and 48s.  The 48s allow me room for two thick pairs of socks comfortably.

If you are going to using chemical heater packs, I suggest sticking them to the top toe of your shoe under the bootie.  The won't compress your toes that way and will get better air circulation / stay warmer.

Answer (score 4):

Back when I did winter riding in Minnesota (in temps down to 0F), I used [neoprene booties](http://www.performancebike.com/bikes/Product_10052_10551_1082829_-1_400094__400094) over my regular cycling shoes.  These kept the feet warm and also kept out moisture.

At the time I was using regular "toe clip" pedals, so no shoe cleats, but reputedly one could use the things with cleats by cutting out the bottom around the cleat (though obviously losing some moisture resistance in the process).

Another useful thing is "toe warmers" -- small chemical packs kind of like drug desiccant packs which produce heat in response to oxygen and moisture.  These are available at stores selling hunting and camping goods, and some stores selling to folks who work outside a lot.

Comment: I have neoprene booties that support cleats. They work wonders to keep my feet warm in temperatures as low as -5C. It hasn't been colder here since I got them but I'm certain they'll work in -10C. I have one of the winter models from BBB: http://bbbcycling.com/bike-wear/shoecovers/

Comment: @daniel-r-hicks Where do you place the toe warmers and how comfortable is it to ride with (e.g. with the extra material in your shoe)? Thanks

Comment: @mattsolar - The toe warmers are little paper packets -- quite thin.  Generally you place them in the toes of your shoes, so your toes will be on top of them (with socks in between) when you put your feet in the shoes.  They do consume a little space, so not comfortable if your shoes are already a hair tight up there, but rarely a problem otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

15 F and even moderate bike speeds means a wind chill that is at best 0 F, and in any ambient wind ( and there is always wind in the winter ) and it gets to -10 F.

The problem may not be enough insulation in the shoes, but not enough insulation altogether. Due to the way the body reacts to cold temps the feet and hands are the first to feel the cold. Sometimes the right way to keep your feet warm is to put on a jacket. Insulation on your hands and feet can help, but if core is not warm enough, they don't do much good.

Hard exercise in those temps is difficult because it's very easy to overdress and sweat out your layers. Too much insulation can eventually make you colder and not enough means you can't keep your hands and feet warm.

Having said all that, overboots seem like a good idea to me. 
40 Below makes overboots that are generally well regarded and they even have a pair that can be easily adapted to bike shoes.

[Fourty Below Overboots](https://www.40below.com/products_detail.php?ProductID=1)

Comment: My "super-cold" setup is a set of those overboots silicon sealed over a set of Lakes.  Pretty bomb proof so far.  Most people error on the side of too warm for core temperature regulation, which is fine when you aren't out for an extended period.  It's hands and feet that are more difficult since the body shunts blood from your extremities to your core when you start getting cold.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [45Nrth Wolvhammer](http://45nrth.com/products/footwear/wolvhammer) I have several friends who have been using them on to ride their fat bikes on cold snowy days and love them.